# Why sentences are made short?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

Sentence: "The work that has been done by you is useful".
I have seen this whole sentence written as " The work done by you is useful ". 
Why writers remove "that has been" and only retain "done" ?
What's the logic behind this?

Comment: Logically, just *Your work is useful* gets the praise across more succinctly. There's always the slight suggestion that *Your work **has been** useful* might be followed by ***...but** it's no longer relevant today*.

Comment: Writers do this because speakers do this. Speakers do this (probably) because it is shorter and still clear. Language (real language, spoken language, is almost never designed: it is just whatever people do when they speak).

Answer (score 3):

> 1. The work that has been done by you is useful
> 2. The work done by you is useful

Both sentences are correct. Some people call #2 a [reduced](https://www.thoughtco.com/reduced-relative-clauses-1211107) version of #1.

However, in the modern framework, these are two different constructions but are semantically equivalent. #1 has a relative clause functioning as a post-modifier, whose relativized element is "work". In #2, "done by you" is a past participle functioning as post-modifier.

The choice is usually a matter of style.

Answer (score -1):

The logic behind this is that there are longer and shorter ways of saying the same thing, depending on the person, the context and the intention.

Sometimes people choose longer ways because they may sound more impressive or because that's how they speak or to make a particular point.

But most of the time, most of us tend to use shorter ways of saying things because doing so saves time and produces the same result.

There may be considerations of politeness or context or company.

So, while enjoying a meal in the company of strangers you might say:

> Please excuse me a moment; I shall be right back

while, to your spouse you are more likely to say:

> Half a mo; I need a pee

or something similar.

In the examples you give, the meaning is the same. The former is a bit more formal; the second is briefer and to the point.